# accessing intent views from activity class to java class

Tags: android, android-intent

I have one java class and one Activity class.

In my java class, it consists of business logic. I want to access the Textviews from activity class to my java class.

If I create an object to activity class. I got all views in activity class as NULL and getting null pointer Exception.

This is my java class here I have created object for activity class and here I am getting `NULLpointerException` for `tdoor.setText()` method.

```
public class Subscribe {

viewtiles vtiles=new viewtiles();


public void sendMessageforstatus(String status)
{
        if(status.contains("Door is open"))
        {


                vtiles.tdoor.setText("OPEN");

        }

        else if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("Door is close"))
        {

            vtiles.tdoor.setText("CLOSE");
        }
```

This is my activity layout class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tilesview);

    tdoor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.door2);
}
```

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_height="match_parent" 
       android:background="@android:color/background_light" > 
       <TextView android:layout_width="79dp" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:text="Door" 
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
           android:layout_marginLeft="52dp" 
           android:id="@+id/door1" 
           android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
           android:textSize="20dp" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can u plzzz help me for this problem...

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
   >
<TextView
            android:layout_width="79dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Door"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"

            android:id="@+id/door1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

Comment: When you create your `viewtiles` activity by `new viewtiles()` you are creating a whole new activity instead of accessing the already existing activity - which I assume you want to access. Beside that it is a bad design to access an activity (a controller class in sense of MVC) from a business logic class. You should better access the business logic class from the activity.

Comment: then how can i access existing activity? @gus42

Comment: You can access the existing activity by passing a reference as a parameter to your `Subscribe` class, e.g. `public Subscribe(viewtiles vtiles)`. But see my comment before: this is a bad design.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass TextView object into your Java class,

```
public void sendMessageforstatus(String status, TextView txt)
{
   // example
   txt.setText("OPEN");
}
```

Comment: iam calling sendMessageforstatus() method from another activity, so i cant pass the TectView object